# Tell if we are running linux inside WSL?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a few linux systems, including those running as WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on a Windows machine.

I'd like to be able that a script/program/whatever can tell if it's running inside of WSL.  I could do something hacky like look for the existence of /mnt/c/...   but that could just be a Windows disk mounted on a Linux system.

Is there a clean way to do this, or is WSL too much like a virtual machine to know that we aren't running inside of Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uname -a
```

Seems like quite a reasonable solution to me.

```
~# uname -a
Linux Eve 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #476-Microsoft Fri Nov 01 16:53:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The clear denotation of "Microsoft" in the uname makes it clear that we're running in WSL. Now in fairness to your example, this *could* be just a forged uname string. But for where the rubber meets the road, this more than fills the bill.

Comment: That was it!  I saw "Linux" in a plain "uname" - and it didn't occur to me that there'd be something useful in the rest of it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Do mark that this is the answer if you find your problem has been solved :)

Comment: Ack - thanks for the reminder, I hit the vote box but not the checkmark.  Thanks for the answer!